# Не выходит установить SQL developer

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

Пытаюсь установить sql developer, скачал с оф сайта - установка не пошла по таким же причинам. Ранее на машине был установлен mysql, но его удалили, почистил реестр, но понять почему не получается установить не могу

стоит jdk11, jre так же стоит

попытался скачать с торрента sql, в надежде на то, что какие-то модули будут скачаны, но проблема осталась

сама ошибка: Warning - could not install some modules

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: пофиксил замечание

Comment: может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809319/sql-developer-error-with-disable-modules-and-continue

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Developer IDE также поставляется в виде zip-файла. Так что ничего устанавливать не надо. Просто распакуйте его и запустите

`sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper64W.exe`

Comment: Все верно, при распаковке архива и попытке запуска .exe файла и вылетает предупреждение

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809319/sql-developer-error-with-disable-modules-and-continue

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил

Comment: Приятно слышать, что вы решили проблему. Пожалуйста, не забудьте принять решение в качестве ответа.